# Monitoring External Jobs in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I have started to look at Hudson as a replacement for CruiseControl. I would like to use it to monitor external jobs as well. I have tried to follow the advice on this page: [Monitoring External Jobs](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Monitoring+external+jobs)

When I run this command:

```
java -jar hudson-core-1.309.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
        at hudson.EnvVars.initMaster(EnvVars.java:197)
        at hudson.EnvVars.(EnvVars.java:192)
        at hudson.Main.getHudsonHome(Main.java:71)
        at hudson.Main.run(Main.java:61)
        at hudson.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

Comment: So, it turns out it's broken in the current version of Hudson. I went back to an older version (1.291) to get it to work. But, because my installation of Hudson requires a login, it doesn't work. This message http://www.nabble.com/Monitoring-external-cron-jobs-td23511569.html#a23511569 suggests it will be moved to the CLI jar shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add servlet.jar to the executing classpath.  hudson-core-1.309.jar is built to run in a web container and thus doesn't have that included.

Comment: I am running hudson stand alone (ie: "java -jar hudson.war"). There is no servlet.jar inside hudson.war. Or, at least not in side the expanded war directory that is created.

Comment: Right - I think that the above means that Hudson needs to have a servlet.jar or at least a servlet-api.jar on the classpath to find HttpServletRequest.